# #include <x/y.h> works from one project file but not from other? need to change file configurations?

Tags: c, eclipse, compilation

I have a some code files and a directory with some header files in sub-directories, structured like this:

```
code\my_file.c
code2\other_file.c
headers
```

where `headers` contains the sub-directories `openssl, curl`.

When I use `#include <openssl/evp.h>` inside `my_file.c` it fails with:

> `fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory`

However, it works from `other_file.c`

Additionally, when I include the full path `#include "../headers/openssl/evp.h` it works fine.

Is there a reason one file in my project knows to find the `openssl` dir and the other doesn't?

*Using Eclipse*

I tried changing properties, by adding an include path:

[image]

[image]

but it didn't work...

Comment: It looks like a make-build issue, could you add your makefile/scons/compilation command/...?

Comment: Eclipse was designed to be a mysterious linker error generator. Crap like this is exactly the reason why it shouldn't be used. Be aware that the path you include as per your answer get silently translated to an absolute path behind the lines, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905795/eclipse-cant-find-header-filers-even-though-include-paths-have-been-set). So the IDE meltdown may just continue from there. I'd strongly recommend to avoid Eclipse at all costs.

Comment: I saw after the change that my project has changed its `my_package/.cproject` file (added `<listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="&quot;${workspace_loc:/headers}&quot;"/>` line) - is that the silent translation you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This what fixed it for me but if someone has another answer, I'd love to hear it*

So, it turns out I just needed to do the exact same thing in the GNU C++ tab also:

[image]

[image]