# Eclipse C constants defined in header could not be resolved

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm writing a C program where I use a header to declare some functions and define several constants. When I use these constants in my code, I get the error `Symbol 'FOO' could not be resolved`. I have no problems with the declared functions.

I am using Eclipse Neon. I have already verified that the path to the directory containing the header files is added to the Include Path. And I have also restarted Eclipse.

header.h

```
#ifndef __header_h_
#define __header_h_

#define FOO 0x00
#define BAR 0x01

void do_stuff(int x);

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    do_stuff(FOO);
    return 0;
}
```

> ERROR: Symbol 'FOO' could not be resolved

What am I missing here?

Comment: What you'll likely have to do is to add `-I` option (assuming gcc) with the include path, somewhere in a hard to find compiler option setting. Since Eclipse is really nothing but a mysterious linker error generator, I'd recommend using an IDE instead, so you can focus on debugging your code instead of debugging the toolchain.

Comment: Apparently your code looks ok. Just one thing: [using `__` at the start of any identifier is reserved for any use](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3). Maybe try `#ifndef H__HEADER_`?

Comment: @Lundin Wouldn't you classify Eclipse as an IDE? Or did you mean another IDE?

Comment: @KamiKaze Since Eclipse cannot be used for any form of productive development, no I wouldn't classify it as a Development Environment.

Comment: @Lundin As I said, I verified that the directory is in the include path. And I also checked if it is in the (indeed hard to find) compiler option setting.
Also the compiler only seems to have a problem resolving the defined parameters. When I change the number of arguments in the function declaration, I get an error that there are too few arguments to the respective function in the C file. So I assume that the header file is included (more or less) properly.

Comment: You'll get linker errors like these all day, every day - it is perfectly normal with Eclipse. Takes roughly a week to resolve each one, then you can move on to the next. The number of possible Eclipse bugs is infinite. Could be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905795/eclipse-cant-find-header-filers-even-though-include-paths-have-been-set), could be anything. My best advice is to get a better IDE.

Comment: @Lundin while we are here in the comments, do you have suggestions for a (free) IDE that would also support/can be enhanced to support unit testing? Free would be nice but not mandatory.

Comment: Is there another header with same name around that could be picked instead of your desired header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click on the Project `Index > Freshen All Files` and then `Index > Rebuild` fixed the problem