# I have a problem with Eclipse and MinGW : the project cant find gcc( but is included in the bin)

Tags: c, mingw, eclipse-cdt

the console output:

```
12:26:51 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Client ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Client.o" "..\\src\\Client.c" 
Cannot run program "gcc": Impossibile trovare il file specificato.


12:26:51 Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings. (took 41ms)
```

Comment: The bin is included in the PATH

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead of writing comments. Please show the value of PATH. Where exactly did you specify the variable PATH? Did you start Eclipse after modifying PATH? If you open a new `cmd` window, can you run `gcc`? How did you configure your project in Eclipse?

Comment: This is typical Eclipse foolery. You need to find some sort of Eclipse option that adds relative paths then ensure that these are passed on to gcc as `-I`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905795/eclipse-cant-find-header-filers-even-though-include-paths-have-been-set) for example. I would however strongly recommend you to not use Eclipse and instead get a sane IDE that lets you be productive.

Comment: Most of the problems recognized as "Eclipse foolery" are not Eclipse's fault but premature option fiddling by users. For me it works since version "Europa" that is for about 12 years for MinGW, Java, Keil-C, Ruby, and so on.

Comment: @AlessandroPalmiotta What happens if you try the shown command `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Client.o" "..\\src\\Client.c` on the command line in your project's home?

Comment: @Lundin I only asked to get some more information because the OP wrote "The bin is included in the PATH" I don't generally recommend to modify `PATH` manually.

Comment: @Lundin What is a sane C++ IDE?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Pretty much anything that isn't based on Eclipse. Crossworks, Codeblocks, IAR, Notepad++, Visual Studio etc etc.

Comment: @thebusybee Sorry, but that's simply not true. Wanting to organize your code in different folders is not "premature option fiddling" but a very likely and very reasonable use-case. The culprit is the Eclipse "shadow file system" with the workspace disconnected from the folder structure on the desk. Someone wants to add exisiting files and folders to their project! Damn, didn't see that coming!

Comment: @Lundin Well, I don't know what Eclipse did to you, and I don't want to know. This is not the place to discuss pros and cons of different IDEs. I have no problems to organize my projects in several folders and sub-folders. The "fiddled options" issue is based on several years of watching and helping coworkers use Eclipse and other IDEs.

Comment: @thebusybee If you have ever used Eclipse, like me who have used 4 different ports of it, you will know that the IDE is perfectly willing and capable of messing itself up without the user touching anything at all. Thus you will spend approximately 33% of your dev time debugging mysterious linker errors caused by the IDE. The fact that you _need_ to watch and help coworkers with the IDE rather then the code says it all.

Comment: @Lundin I used Eclipse since "Europa" to this day, on Windows and Linux, that counts as some 15 releases, and some forks. And no, I never had problems you describe. The reason I need to help my coworkers is that they "optimized" the project settings without knowing what they do. They hardly have an idea what compiling and linking means. It would and did happen with *any* IDE they use.

Comment: @Lundin The same belongs to their use of µVision (only usable for some embedded systems), Notepad++ (which is not a "sane" IDE, just an enhanced editor), Visual Studio (several versions from 6 to this day, crashes often and is hardly responsive) and QtCreator. The latter is quite OK but limited compared to a general purpose IDE. **But as I said, this is not the place to bash IDEs!**

Comment: @AlessandroPalmiotta Please answer some of Bodo's questions. Most important is: Can you run GCC from the command line without giving it a full path?