# E219 Error when compiling C code in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

When compiling a header file containing the following extract

```c
#include <_Reg/IfxGpt12_reg.h>
#include <_Impl/IfxGpt12_cfg.h>
#include <Port/Std/IfxPort.h>
```

The following error is shown

> ctc E219: ["..\0_Src\4_McHal\Tricore_PinMap\IfxGpt12_PinMap.h" 32/1]
> cannot open #include file "_Reg/IfxGpt12_reg.h"

However, the header files do exist in the directory! Is this a toolchain problem?

Comment: So it can't find this include file. First thing I would replace `<>` with `" "`

Comment: Mysterious linker problems is perfectly normal for Eclipse, expect these to happen frequently. You probably have to set include paths manually, for each directory which isn't the root one. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905795/eclipse-cant-find-header-filers-even-though-include-paths-have-been-set) and be aware of the bug explained in the answer. But the only viable long-term solution if you wish to avoid "the daily linker problem" is to get rid of Eclipse.

Comment: @Lundin It is not linker but preprocessor problem.. I like Eclipse BTW. You can avoid its inherent problems like this by not relying on its built-in build system and working with "Makefile projects"

Comment: @EugeneSh. Tried that no change.

Comment: @EugeneSh. If you can't build from it, then it's not an IDE but a glorified notepad.exe :) Btw avoiding it might not be easily achieved if you rely on bloatware libs from a MCU vendor that require you to use their particular hellspawn of Eclipse, with their own particular CRT, linker scripts and non-standard extensions.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry, your answer actually worked. Surely there is an easier way of doing this.. I have over 100 subfolders in total..

Comment: @Lundin Glorified notepad is what I need:) In fact it is not true. It has a nice debugger front-end, and you can its buttons to do the stuff you need. +plugins. I agree that custom Eclipse builds from MCU vendors are pure evil. But in this case you can't move from Eclipse at all :) If they really want to customize - do it as plugin.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The debugger is horrible IMO. Too crude and made for PC.