# Eclipse "error: no such file or directory" while the header does exist

Tags: c, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on automatic unit testing of ESP32 code in eclipse 2022-06 using google test.
For this I have made a new project and connected it with the ESP32 code using a header file.
I have also connected the unit test project with the ESP32 code via

```
properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols.
```

As seen in the picture below.
When running the ESP32 code I get no errors but when I try to run the unit test I get `"fatal error: freertos/FreeRTOS.: No such file or directory"`. However this path can be found in the EPS32 project that im testing.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
[image]

```
#include "main/main.h"
```

Part of the unit test code

```
#ifndef MAIN_DOT_H
#define MAIN_DOT_H

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stddef.h>
    #include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
    #include "freertos/task.h"
    #include "rom/ets_sys.h"
    #include "rom/gpio.h"
    #include "esp_intr_alloc.h"
    #include "esp_attr.h"
    #include "driver/timer.h"
    #include "esp_task_wdt.h"                               
    #include "soc/timer_group_struct.h"
    #include "soc/timer_group_reg.h"
    #include "driver/mcpwm.h"
```

Part of the header file

```
#include "main.h"
```

Part of the ESP32 code

To repeat the question, how can I solve this error?

Comment: The message looks like it's failing on `freertos/FreeRTOS.` does it really say that, or is it really `FreeRTOS.h` ?

Comment: @SteveFriedl it says freertos/FreeRTOS.h because thats how the header is declared in the code. And as seen in the picture I made a direct link to the main folder where freertos is in and the freertos folder where FreeRTOS.h is in.

Comment: If you have `freertos` both in the include path and in the `#include` string, you will get it twice in the resulting name. Is that what you want? Otherwise remove one of them.

Comment: click on the language to see language settings

Comment: On my machine (not a mac), the path is `.../esp_idf/components`, not `.../esp_idf_components` - could that be part of the issue?

Comment: @BoP the include path is onyl so that eclipse can find the location of the header in #include

Comment: @SteveFriedl no, the path is the same in the paths and symbols as on the file explorer

Comment: @Tarvos if the header includes "freertos/freertos.h" then you don't have to add the "freertos" folder in your include paths.

Comment: @Fra93 thanks for the clarity. I tried it as a test.

Comment: @Tarvos aaand? Did it work?

Comment: @Fra93 no, I still get the same error

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905795/eclipse-cant-find-header-filers-even-though-include-paths-have-been-set. Ensure you have all sub directories set as mentioned in the question, that they boil down into an `-I` command passed to gcc and that you have no exotic characters in the absolute file path. Or alternatively, you can uninstall Eclipse and forget that you ever heard about it, then live happily ever after.

Comment: @Lundin thx for the reaction, but i got around 50 subfolders maybe more. So I think i'm gonna forget about eclipse. If you place your comment as a answer others can find it easier.

Comment: Drop Eclipse and repeat the same issue with any other IDE. :-D You need to understand how the _underlying_ tools work. Get your project's layout nice. Only then attempt to setup your project in the IDE. -- BTW, **you** told the IDE to pass the erroneous options to the compiler, which produced the message, finally. It was not the IDE.

Comment: Like Bonnie Tyler said after a week of trying to get her program to link in Eclipse: "Turn around!" It's not too late to switch to an IDE suitable for programming.