# can't get Eclipse on Windows 10 to compile C source imported from existing folder of .c and .h files

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I have an eclipse hello world project that works.

But imported folder of .c and .h source code gets build error:  "undefined reference to [any functions within import]"

Hello world project installed here:
C:\SDK\AmbiqSuite_R3.1.1\boards\apollo3_evb\examples\hello_world\

Workspace is installed here:
C:\Users\Doug\eclipse-workspace\

Have copied import files to "everywhere":
project\src
project\gcc
project\

eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0) on Windows 10

Comment: In Eclipse, you always have to fiddle around with some well-hidden options to get anything to link. Check out this Q&A for how to add sub folders while using C/gcc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905795/eclipse-cant-find-header-filers-even-though-include-paths-have-been-set. I would strongly recommend to pick a different IDE though, unless you want to troubleshoot mysterious linker errors all day instead of doing actual programming.